# Dynamic routing with nginx, lua and redis

Tags: nginx, redis, lua, openresty

I am trying to make nginx perform proxying based on the URI with the help of lua and redis.
So far, I am able to successfully proxy simple URI like '/hello' to desired target. Was able to achieve this by saving the mappings in a redis hashmap something like,

```
HGETALL "127.0.0.1:8080"
1) "/demo1/test/hello4"
2) "example.com/demo1/test/hello4"
3) "/hello"
4) "example.com/hello"
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  2;
error_log logs/error.log info;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            resolver 8.8.4.4;  # use Google's open DNS server

            set $target '';
            access_by_lua '
                local http_host = ngx.var.http_host
                
                if not http_host then
                    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "no http-host found")
                    return ngx.exit(400)
                end

                local redis = require "resty.redis"
                local red = redis:new()

                red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 second

                local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
                if not ok then
                    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to connect to redis: ", err)
                    return ngx.exit(500)
                end

                local fPath, err = red:hget(http_host, ngx.var.uri)

                if not fPath then
                    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "No fPath: ", err)
                    return ngx.exit(500)
                end


                ngx.var.target = fPath

            ';

            proxy_pass $target;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I also want to handle dynamic URI's like example:-

```
user/id/1 -> "example.com/user/id/1", 
user/id/2 -> "example.com/user/id/2", 
user/id/3 -> "example.com/user/id/3", 
and so on....
```

I am not sure how can I create a key value pair in redis and lua logic for this case which can handle the dynamicity of the id's.
I tried looking but haven't been able to find the right direction or some resource to aid me in figuring this out.

Any help would be really great!

Comment: I have writen something like this in the past. My keys are the possible URIs like yours /user/id/3, /user/id/*. In my lua code try to find an exact match first. After that I try to find the best matching wildcard match. It was a quite complex lua script. Today I would use `njs` for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this in production, I would recommend using mature API gateways like [Apache APISIX](https://apisix.apache.org/) or [Kong](https://konghq.com/install/#kong-community). To implement it yourself, maybe you could store paths with wildcard or Lua patterns in Redis to allow later matching to the original URI. Applying some simple heuristics would help reduce the range of checking.

Comment: You may want to check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70843680/location-based-redirect-when-urls-can-not-use-regular-expressions-to-match  lol